# Excel drop down selections changing color of cells in other columns within the same row

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a sheet in which drop down list selections in one  column trigger one or more cells on the same row but on different columns to change color.

For instance, cells in Column C have a drop down list with three options (Let's say options are "Yellow," "Blue," and "Green") created using the data validation function.  I want each of these choices to color additional cells on the same row, and each drop down option needs to color different cells.

For example, selecting "Yellow" in C3 would cause cells E3, F3, and G3 to turn yellow, while selecting "Blue" in C3 would change D3, H3, and I3 blue.  I need drop down selections in the entire Column C to similarly change the same cells on their corresponding rows (Choosing "Yellow" on C58 would only change E58, F58, and G58.

I was able to use conditional formatting to create a rule to make this work for a single line, but it took one rule for each drop down selection.

Is there a way to make the rules apply to the entire column while ensuring that changes only occur in response to the drop down selection in the corresponding row?

Comment: `worksheet_change`?

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like the color selection in the row would make the different rows turn different colors. Since you are most of the way there it looks like the easiest is to just use conditional formatting. Now if that makes the sheet too slow to load and update you will need to turn to VBA. But for now go with the conditional, you can model it all like the following.

```
Formula: =$C1="Yellow"
```

Then apply it to the rage `=$E$1:$G$100000`

And similarly for "Blue" the range would be `=$D$1:$D$100000,$H$1:$I$100000`

You get the pattern and keep going from there.